# printing array in rows javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 100 random numbers between 1 and 49.

I would like to print out the array in rows of twelve elements, instead of printing the array in a single line.

Here is the code I have

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
 var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0, l = 100; i < l; i++) {
     arr.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 49)+1)
 }
 document.write(arr);
 document.write("\n");
</script>
```

I need to print the array in rows with 12 elements per row and also need to find the smallest element in the array.

Comment: Did you try something ? Like having a counter for example ?

Comment: Just change `\n` to `<br />`. But you should really avoid using `document.write()` and use proper DOM manipulation instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `splice`:

```
while (arr.length > 0) {
    document.write(arr.splice(0, 12))
}
```

However, after running that code the array will be `[]`. If you don't want to modify the array, use `slice` instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 12) {
    document.write(arr.slice(i, i + 12))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the conventional way of doing it. The array is reset however. Let us know more detail on your requirements.

```
 var arr = [];

function getRandom( num ){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * num)+1;
}

var counter = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     arr.push(getRandom( 49 ));
     counter++;

     if( counter >= 12 ){
         document.write(arr);
         document.write("<br/>");
         arr = [];
         counter = 0;
     }

 }
```